# Single client talking to multiple Servers

Tags: winsock, tcpclient

I'm working on a project where I have a single client that need to open a Telnet session to multiple servers (100) and wait for messages.  The messages are small (< 80 bytes) and will occur at random.

I've read that it's bad form to do this by creating a thread for each "server".  I'm looking for suggestions as to the best way to handle the multiple sites with TCPClient, or Winsock or Catalyst or ???

Thanks for the help !

Gary M

Answer (score 1):

As it is Windows platform, there are many options. You can use Winsock **select** function, or  **WSAPoll**, or **WSAAsyncSelect**, or completition ports.

**select/WSAPoll** work almost like in Posix, and there are plenty of examples, and some ready libraries on how to use those.

**WSAAsyncSelect** will send events to the UI thread (you need to have window for that). If you application has a window, this might be the simplest option, as all activity will occur in the window thread, and library takes care of event serialization.

Also take a look at (it is important as you have more then 64 connections):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169(v=vs.85).aspx

Using Windows completition ports:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms810436.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions!   I'll go thru them and figure out what seems to work best for this application!